# É possível evitar que a tela do usuário se apague em uma página?

Tags: javascript, ux

Acredito que todos os sistemas operacionais possuem a opção para que a tela se apague após um determinado tempo de inatividade do usuário, principalmente como forma de economizar bateria, porém, nem sempre é desejado que isso aconteça.

Por exemplo: ao assistir um vídeo, o usuário possivelmente ficará inativo durante sua reprodução, mas é desejado que a tela não se apague a cada pouco - o que realmente não acontece, por padrão.

Mas e se minha página possuir um comportamento semelhante? Eu posso ter uma publicação em um blog que eu espero que o usuário leve mais tempo para fazer a leitura, ficando inativo durante este período.

- É possível informar ao navegador que a tela não deverá apagar após um período de inatividade do usuário em uma determinada página?
- Esta configuração a partir do JavaScript sobrescreverá as configurações de usuário do sistema operacional?
- Em questão de usabilidade, seria interessante informar ao usuário que a tela não se apagaria nesta página?

Comment: **Obs.:** É fácil achar alguns códigos que prometem fazer isso adicionando um vídeo executando em segundo plano. De preferência, gostaria de soluções que não fizessem isso, pois parecem ser uma forma gambiarra de resolver o problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não existe um padrão ainda. Vários browsers e OSes implementam de uma certa maneira. Isso dito, existem iniciativas de padronização.

- iOS: [UIApplication.idleTimerDisabled](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIApplication/idleTimerDisabled)
- Android: [Wake locks](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/wakelock.html): suporta "system" e "display".
- Windows 8: [Detecção de ociosidade para Windows Phone 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff941090%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).
- FirefoxOS: [navigator.requestWakeLock()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator.requestWakeLock) - Suporta "cpu", "display" e "wifi".
- ChromeApps: [chrome.power.requestKeepAwake()](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/power.html) - suporta "system" e "display".
- Chrome: [navigator.getWakeLock()](https://www.w3.org/TR/wake-lock/#examples) - suporta "system" e "screen".
- Tizen: [tizen.power.request()](https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/2.2.0/org.tizen.web.device.apireference/tizen/power.html#requestidp102368) - suporta "cpu" e "screen".

[Fonte](http://w3c-webmob.github.io/wake-lock-use-cases/).

> É possível informar ao navegador que a tela não deverá apagar após um período de inatividade do usuário em uma determinada página?

Este é o papel destas APIs, entretanto cada uma possui uma implementação (e especificação) diferentes.

> Esta configuração a partir do JavaScript sobrescreverá as configurações de usuário do sistema operacional?

Sim.

> Em questão de usabilidade, seria interessante informar ao usuário que a tela não se apagaria nesta página?

Depende do caso, porém em geral eu consideraria uma boa prática.